# How to filter qt generated moc file when stat code coverage?

Tags: c++, qt, code-coverage

I use visual studio to get code coverage of one qt project. 
But some qt moc auto-generated files lead to a lower coverage score.
I tried to use "vsinstre.exe /exclude:*qt_static_metacall* /exclude:*qt_metacall*" to filter some function related to qt moc files during instrument phrase. But unfortunately, it seems does not work.
Then how to filter those functions/files？
Thanks.